# What does "auf seine Weise" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading an analysis about Kafka's Letter to his father but I was unable to understand what *"auf seine Weise"* means in this sentence:

> "Nicht nur, dass es ihm unmöglich ist, sich gegen seinen Vater aufzulehnen, er war nicht einmal in der Lage, neben dem Vater auf seine Weise zu existieren."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"auf seine Weise" usually translates to "in his own way". In this particular case, the writer uses the construct ("exist in his own way") to emphasize the intensity of dependency from his father by saying, the couldn't exist with an individual personality next to his father.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. So "seine" refers to Kafka here, not his father, right?

Comment: @ZaferCesur yes.